# AWS JWT-Authorizer not supporting "any" audience

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-http-api, aws-jwt-authorizer

It seems to me that the JWT-authorizer in a HTTP-api on AWS API-Gateway does not support adding "any client" as allowed audience.

This becomes a pain if you want to use it for an API where clients get added removed a lot.

Am I missing something (an asterix or something in the configuration), or can't the JWT-authorizer support such cases where clients are added/removed dynamically outside of the IAC?